# MachForm 3.3 + prettyPhoto

Tags: forms, iframe, prettyphoto

I have prettyPhoto and MachForm running on my site. Both work fine individually. What I am trying to do is run MachForm within prettyPhoto's popup window... which works fine except for when my machform has 3 pages to it. So when a user fills out page 1 of machform within prettyPhoto and clicks next to advance to the next page of the form, instead of page 2 of machform loading within prettyphoto, it instead loads on a page of its own.

How do I fix this so that machform's pages 2 and 3 load only within prettyPhoto?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>

<li><a href="/contact?q=prettyphoto&iframe=true&width=50%&height=87%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]">General Inquiries</a></li>
```

The /contact page is machform.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modal! prettyPhoto is great for photos, but it sucks for forms, even when they are done right it's just too buggy even with a basic html form.

I use the modal included from bootstrap. It works good for me.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Also use the iframe embed instead of the js embed. With the js embed I had issues.